# Show google maps component in admin-on-rest panel

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm trying to find an example of how I can use any Google Maps React component (like this one - https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react ) in admin-on-rest framework (https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/).

Does anybody have one to look at?

Thank you.

Comment: Read this link: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1782

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install --save react-google-maps` # or
   `yarn add react-google-maps`
2. `import { GoogleMap,withScriptjs,withGoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps"`

3.

```
 export const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
 <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={8}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 24.715297, lng: 46.671848 }}>
    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: 24.715297, lng: 46.671848 }} />}

  </GoogleMap>))
```

4. call it inside your export const postCreate for example

```
<MyMapComponent
  isMarkerShown
  googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
  loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px`,width:`500px`,paddingTop:`100px` }} />}
  mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}/>
```

hope this help